# Parsing XML column in SQL Alchemy results

Tags: python, sql, xml, pandas, sqlalchemy

All,

I have a sql table that I am accessing in Python that has 3 columns: A, B, C.  Column A has the unique ID, Column B has the timestamp but Column C is the issue. That column is all xml.  My goal is to take that column and parse it out so the labels become the column header.

Example:

```
<TAX>41.25</TAX><GRS>275</GRS><MPY>CredirCard</MPY><CTN>840</CTN>
```

If this were the XML I would like it to create this (as additional columns):

```
TAX      GRS   MPY         CTN  
41.25    275   Credit Card 840
```

I would be okay with converting it to a pandas dataframe of course and then of course utilizing something like either the xml library and lxml.  I could not find an example that did this within a pandas dataframe.  I did find some examples that did this from a true xml file but that is not the case here as the column will have xml structure but will not be an xml file.  I can provide more information if needed.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not valid `XML`, there is no `root`  element.

Read about `XML parsing`: [the-parse-function](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function)